# How can I wrap text wrapping on a jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to display some long text with help of a datatable, but somehow it is not beeing wraped. This means that instead of getting multiple rows of my text, I just get a long line. When I go to my DB and edit my Description field (Field type is text), I can see the text in multiple rows.

I already tried fixing the width of the table to 100%, but then the text line just keeps going outside the table.  I also tried adding word-wrap and flex-wrap, and defining a text-wrap class on my CSS, but it also didn't work.

Any idea how can I solve this?

```
  <div style="font-size:18px;">
    <table class="table-striped table-hover" id="product_table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Group</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Action</th>
          <th class="none">Description DE</th>
          <th class="none">Description EN</th>
          <th class="none">Description ES</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($ProductList as $product)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$product['ProductName']}}</td>
          <td>{{$product['ProductGroupName']}}</td>
          <td>{{$product['ProductListPrice']}}</td>
          <td ><button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect w-md waves-light w-sm-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Edit" data-id="{{$product['ProductID']}}" data-name="{{$product['ProductName']}}" data-group="{{$product['ProductGroupName']}}"
              data-price="{{$product['ProductListPrice']}}" data-descde="{{$product['ProductDescriptionDE']}}" data-descen="{{$product['ProductDescriptionEN']}}" data-desces="{{$product['ProductDescriptionES']}}">Edit</button>
          <td>{{$product['ProductDescriptionDE']}}</td>
          <td>{{$product['ProductDescriptionEN']}}</td>
          <td>{{$product['ProductDescriptionES']}}</td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#product_table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
          "className": "dt-center",
          "targets": "_all"
        }],
        pageLength: 50,
        responsive: true
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found my mistake. The CSS class wasn't correct. Here is how the class should be:

```
.text-wrap{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add `wrap` class in your table.

```
<table class="table-striped table-hover wrap" id="product_table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43760/force-datatable-to-wrap-text#Comment_115199

Comment: I tried that at the beginning, but it didn't work. but I already found a solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: It should work if your datatable version is greater than 1.10.1. You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it works on all kinds of table:

```
table.dataTable tbody td {
  word-break: break-word; word-break: break-all; white-space: normal;
}
```